# Xcode analyzer complaining of CFContextRef stored in an "assign" @property

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-foundation, analyzer

I have a Cocoa class that needs to keep a bitmap context around for a long time to do pixel manipulation.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGContextRef cacheContext; // block of pixels
```

in my class init:

```
// this creates a 32bit ARGB context, fills it with the contents of a UIImage and returns a CGContextRef
[self setCacheContext:[self allocContextWithImage:[self someImage]]];
```

and in dealloc:

```
CGContextRelease([self cacheContext]);
```

The Xcode analyzer companies about the init leaking an object of type CGContextRef and in the dealloc there is a complaint about "incorrect decrement of an object that is not owned by the caller".

I believe this is all ok and it runs perfectly.

How can I tell Xcode that this is all ok and not to complain about it?

Comment: ARC or managed memory? Also, what's the code for the `cacheContext` getter and setter?

Comment: This is non-ARC code, and the getter/setter are just the built-in provided by @property(assign, nonatomic). In init the warning is "allocated object of type 'CGContextRef _Nullable' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1". It is true that it is not further referenced (until dealloc) because it is now stored in an "assign" property for use elsewhere in the class.

Comment: If you're using the generated getter/setting then you shouldn't need `nonatomic`. Try taking that out and see if it helps. I'd also try removing the `assign` property (it can't hurt) and see if that makes the analyzer happy (one problem is that your retains are being done asymmetrically—a setter that retains should release on dealloc, and a setter that doesn't retain shouldn't release).

Comment: Removing the assign and/or nonatomic don't help. I am creating the CFContext and simply storing it in an assign property - just a local variable to the class really. I correctly release it in dealloc so that it persists for the life of my class object. My setters/getters should not be retaining or releasing anything - the CFContextRef is owned by me and I need to release it (and I do).

Comment: ... ran out of comment room ... My suggestion would be to change the setter to `retain` (or roll your own to use `CFRetain`) then `CGContextRef ctx = [self alloctContextWithImage:...]; self.cacheContext = ctx; CGContextRelease(ctx);` Now you're using a balanced retain/release (and you might avoid a bug in the future!)

Comment: I don't doubt your retain/release is balanced, we just have to convince the analyzer of that. Also, have you tried not declaring this a property and simply using an ivar?

Comment: How will a synthesized retain know what to do with a CGContextRef? The only way it works is by adding  __attribute__((NSObject)) but that seems like it is ARC specific. I have not tried an ivar without a property as I prefer to keep the property, but that is a possibility.

Do you think I need to use CFAutorelease() and write my own getter/setter with a retain property?

Comment: A getter does not seem to work: `@property (assign, nonatomic) CGContextRef myContext;` But then my getter defined as: `-(CGContextRef)myContext{ return(_myContext); }` gives an error "use of undeclared identifier_myContext" so there is no ivar created.

Comment: If you use `nonatomic` and write your own getters, you have to create your own variable storage (i.e. an ivar). I love property declarations, but honestly in this case you'd be better off with just an ivar for two reasons: (a) this appears to be an internal property that probably shouldn't be exposed and (b) it doesn't follow the retain/release contract for properties. The later is probably the reason the analyzer is complaining.

Comment: It does need to be exposed. I have master controller where the context is created and then several NSOperation objects to work on the context. Currently they are passed the master controller and obtain the context that way. I would think a nonatomic getter is more simple than an atomic one, but it doesn't seem to matter since the _name is not valid either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, given the discussion here's what I think would solve the analyzer complaints, let you keep your formal property, and not break any memory management rules.

Declare a read-only property:

```
@property (readonly) CGContextRef cacheContext;
```

Assign the ivar directly when it's created

```
_cacheContext = [self allocContextWithImage:self.someImage];
```

Release it in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    CGContextRelease(_cacheContext);
    [super dealloc];
}
```